# Java guessing game : need to improve

Tags: java

I’m new to programming and I need to create a 1-100 random number guessing game. The computer will pick a number and we have 5 tries to guess it. It will provide hints such as too high or too low.I have managed to get this farr BUT

I also need to make it so that pressing **1 displays new game** with **2 being instructions and 3 being exit.** I also want to know how to **add 5 tries**. Any useful websites or help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGuessingGame {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            int secretNumber;

            secretNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            int guess;

            do {

                  System.out.print("Enter a guess (1-100): ");

                  guess = keyboard.nextInt();

                  if (guess == secretNumber)

                        System.out.println("Your guess is correct. Congratulations!");

                  else if (guess < secretNumber)

                        System.out

                                   .println("Your guess is smaller than the secret number.");

                  else if (guess > secretNumber)

                        System.out

                                   .println("Your guess is greater than the secret number.");

            } while (guess != secretNumber);

      }

}
```

Comment: "*Any useful websites [...]*" - Off-site content is off-topic for StackOverflow. --- In order to help you, we need to know with which concept you are struggling. The more information we have, the better we can help. --- Some remarks on your code: Please reduce the number of blank lines in your code. - Even if possible, you should not omit opening and closing parenthesis around `if`, `else`, ...

Comment: And what has gone wrong with your own attempt?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this for your code:

1.- for your menu or options you would have to create a separated method where you print the options and another for the instructions.

2.-after creating those methods you should use a case-statement loop so that way yo can choose 1 or 2 or 3 and make things happen.

3.- to make your program to only have 5 tries i suggest you using a counter like "count = 0;" and then adding 1 each time you try to guess at the end of your do-while loop like "count += 1; or count = count + 1;"

As far as websites. I would suggest you either look at Java official docs as these will prove to be your best friend along your career. They have a lot of examples from beginner to advanced level. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

**How to make 1 display new game with 2 being instructions and 3 being exit**

IF you want these input to interrupt the program, it is typically done with a loop which checks the input i.e.

`while (input != "1" && input != "2" ...`

You can use the `break` condition to get out of the loop and handle the interruptions.

If you don't need interrupts then you can just put that code before the guessing like below I did.

**How to add 5 tries**

You loop 5 iterations and adjust your loop condition accordingly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int secretNumber;

        secretNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("(1) displays new game\n (2) instructions\n (3) being exit");
        int guess;
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (guess == 3) {
            int nOfAttempts = 0;
            do {

                System.out.print("Enter a guess (1-100): ");

                guess = keyboard.nextInt();

                if (guess == secretNumber)

                    System.out.println("Your guess is correct. Congratulations!");

                else if (guess < secretNumber)

                    System.out

                            .println("Your guess is smaller than the secret number.");

                else if (guess > secretNumber)

                    System.out

                            .println("Your guess is greater than the secret number.");
                nOfAttempts++;

            } while (guess != secretNumber && nOfAttempts < 5);
        }
    }

}
```